# Regular Graph Question: Each face bounded by n edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have been struggling with this question for a while now, and I'm not sure how to proceed:

A simple-connected, planar graph has $v$ vertices, $e$ edges and $f$ faces.
Each face is bounded by $n$ edges, and each vertex has degree $d$.

Use $f+v-e=2$ to show that $f=\frac{4d}{2d+2n-dn}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  we have $$f\cdot n =2 e$$ and $$v\cdot d = 2e\implies v= fn/d$$ So $$f +fn/d -fn/2 =2$$ thus $$2fd+2fn -fnd =4d$$ so $$f = {4d \over 2d+2n-nd}$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Since the graph is $d$-regular, what is the relation between $d$, $v$ and $e$ (use Handshaking Lemma)? If each face is bounded by $n$ edges, what is the relation between $f$, $e$ and $n$? Then, how can we combine these results using Euler's Characteristic Formula?